# Read/Write Image from local File

Tags: android, android-image

How do I read and write image to/from a local file in android?

I want to take an image from a file, save it in memory and then read it from file.

I am using this code to write image in file:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  String fileName=GetFileName().replace('.', ' ')+".png";
  File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +fileName);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(out));
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);


  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        wb.loadUrl(sendUrl);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {              

            String imgPath= data.getExtras().get("Uri").toString();

            bm = BitmapFactory  .decodeFile(imgPath);
            }
  }
```

How can I read the image back?

Comment: app crashed when i  try to get image from file Problem is here   String imgPath= data.getExtras().get("Uri").toString();

             bm = BitmapFactory .decodeFile(imgPath);

Answer (score 0):

Try this---

```
 Uri mUriSavedImage;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 String fileName=GetFileName().replace('.', ' ')+".png";
 File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +fileName);
 mUriSavedImage= Uri.fromFile(out);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUriSavedImage);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);


 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    wb.loadUrl(sendUrl);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {              

        String imgPath= mUriSavedImage.getPath();

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
        }
 }
```